# PHP 5.5 FastCGI Caching

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I've implemented FastCGI caching on our site, and have seen great speed improvements.  However the FastCGI cache key does not seem to be unique enough.  If I login, my name appears in the header.  However the next person to login still sees my name in the header, assuming the cache is still valid.

Is there a way to make the cache key unique on a per-user basis?  Ideally using a unique identifier from the user's Cookies or a PHP Session?  I tried implemented the answer below, but Nginx failed to restart.

[Log in value from Set-Cookie header in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138503/log-in-value-from-set-cookie-header-in-nginx)

Note my cache key looks like this:

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

Update:
  My thought is if I can parse the HTTP headers sent to Nginx, then I can grab the PHP SESSION ID and use that.  However I cannot find an example of how to do this anywhere.  Right now I have something like this, which doesn't work.

```
http_cookie ~* PHPSESSID=([0-9a-z]+) {
    set $ses_id $1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the above problem using the [Nginx ngx_http_userid_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_userid_module.html).  The hardest part was actually finding the module, implementing the solution was quite trivial.

I used their example configuration:

```
userid         on;
userid_name    uid;
userid_domain  example.com;
userid_path    /;
userid_expires 365d;
userid_p3p     'policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CUR ADM OUR NOR STA NID"';
```

And then added the userid to my fastCGI cache key:

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri$uid_got";
```

Hopefully this answer helps someone discover this useful module quicker than I did.